# Access const function in another const javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, function, react-hooks

I have a react native project.
There I have a Game.js file with my Game inside. I need to trigger the GameStart() function but cant because its inside another function: `

```
export const MyGrid = () => {
  ...

  const GameStart = async () => {
      ...
  };
```

I want to access GameStart() from another file

I tried to move GameStart outside the MyGrid const but it would work as I want. The vars are also inside the MyGrid const. I also cant move useStates outside of MyGrid.

Comment: `GameStart` doesn't even exist until `MyGrid` is called. In general bindings are private to the scope they have been created in. There are ways to make them available outside, but which way to choose and whether it makes sense to do it depends on the specifics of this code. Please provide more information.

Comment: Here is some code from my file: https://pastebin.com/QEew9cYpd
Im creating a react native screen in with this

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dzHQW8iS

Comment: Pass the `GameStart` function as a prop down to the component that should call it